# Send HTTP Request with utf-8 unicode in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, http, utf-8, http-headers

I need to send the following json dictionary with utf-8 enconding, I used the request.setValue to encode utf-8 as following but isn't working,

```
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("true", forHTTPHeaderField: "ajaxRequest")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("false", forHTTPHeaderField: "cdata")
request.setValue("\(putSoftoken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "op")
request.setValue("\(xAuthToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let json: [String: Any] = [
    "query":[],
    "path":[],
    "header":[[
        ... JSON ...
    "method":"POST"
]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

print("putSoftToken:", json)

request.httpBody = jsonData

//create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in ...
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data It would be UTF8 anyway. What's your question exactly? How do you know it's not working? Or is the response that i's following UTF8? It's unclear. You are aware that you are doing `request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` and then `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`, it's keeping only the last value, you know that?

Comment: @Larme The middleware is rejecting special characters I'm sending ("+") when I encrypt some parameters from the body of the http.request, and how is that keeping only the last value ?

Comment: Do the test. Header fields are unique. So you are replacing the value for "Content-Type", just print `request.allHTTPHeaderFields`. It's rejecting because the unwanted characters are where exactly? In the body? That's not about UTF8, since "+" is valid. That's about invalid characters? What are you sending exactly?